# How to read a Binary Frame on a Web Socket?

Tags: websocket, binary

I'm trying to understand the communication between slither.io client and web socket. While I'm reading WS packages the only thing that I can see is "Binary Frame (Opcode 2)". How can I do to read those messages?. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slither.io uses [binary frames](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11.8) to exchange data. As far as I know neither Chrome, nor Firefox allow you to read raw binary data. Try something like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to sniff the traffic.

Comment: Is the data returned in binary frames in order to protect the data and hide it client-side to stop attackers?

Comment: @JackNicholson No, it's likely because the server needs to save bandwidth, so the payload is compressed (like zlib) and then unpacked once it reaches the client. The data being in binary is just an added plus to prevent people from trying to read them raw.